# Getting error when renewing vault token

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We are using HashiCorp's [Python SDK](https://github.com/ianunruh/hvac) to access Vault. And have a simple code to renew the token that calls `/v1/auth/token/renew-self` Vault API behind the scenes.

```
   client = hvac.Client(
                        url=credentials['vault_addr'],
                        token = credentials['vault_token'],
                        verify=False) 
   try:
        client.renew_token()
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError('Could not renew Vault token')
```

When i make this call, i get this error from the Vault Backend

> failed to renew entry: policies have changed, not renewing

Did a bit of digging in the Vault code and i see this is the source of the exception

```
if !policyutil.EquivalentPolicies(cert.Policies, req.Auth.Policies) {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("policies have changed, not renewing")
}
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the policies associated to that token has changed, so it can't be renewed because it has associated the previous policies, that are deprecated.

Instead of renewing it, you should create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 0.10.4: https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/4829 .